# Run first project in android studio without access to internet

Tags: android

How can i run first project in android studio without access to internet? 
I get error for Gradle. I don'n have internet. Can i run and execute project in android studio without internet?

Comment: Of course one can.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to *run* anything without internet. The only issue you might run into is if you haven't downloaded all of your project's dependencies prior to running/compiling a project.

When you add dependencies to your gradle dependencies, Android Studio will download those dependencies for you. If you do not have internet and have undownloaded dependencies in gradle, then your project will not run.

Comment: i don't add any library in my project, just create simple project with MainActivity and no any code or dependency. But project can't build .